# CoreBluetooth and iBeacon: any conflicts?

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, ibeacon

I have got a chip that has a iBeacon service as well as a standard BLE service.

I would like to use the **iBeacon** service to trigger the app that I am developing when entering a BLE signal range.

Once active I'd like the app to scan for peripherals using **CoreBluetooth** and then connect to the chip.

**Is this against Apple terms and conditions**?

Answer (score 1):

Apple has no known restrictions on this setup.  In fact, this is how the [RadBeacon](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/radbeacon/id789301891?mt=8) configuration app works.

Using this technique, detecting a beacon in the background will only give your app 5 seconds of background running time, which generally is not enough time to reliably complete Bluetooth pairing and data exchange.  Your best bet would be to present a local notification to the user on beacon detection, and then if the user brings the app to the foreground, do the pairing.

An alternative would be to extend background running time using a technique like described in my blog post [here.](http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2014/11/13/extending-background-ranging-on-ios.html)  That post shows how to range for beacons in the background, but the same technique will work for bluetooth communication tasks.

Comment: Hello, thanks, 5 seconds sounds like a problem.. I have extended the background running time by setting communicates with BLE accessories. This should overcome the issue I presume. Correct?

Comment: I'm uncertain if the BLE communication over GATT will keep your app running in the background, but you can try.  If it does not, you may need to start a background process as described in the linked blog post.